# Adding 9000 options dynamically to select in javascript taking too long on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would appreciate if somebody helps me creating optimized code for adding 9000+ options dynamically to select box. Basically for simplicity for every option I am keeping text and value both as index of for loop.

I have tried many options like:

1. Creating option element string at once for all 9000 records and then adding to select element using both jquery and plain javascript

2.

```
for loop { 
    options[options.length] = new Option(text, value);
}
```

and then:

```
selectElement.options.add(options);
```

3 .

```
var objOption = document.createElement("option");
objOption.value = value;
objOption.text = text;
htmlElement.options.add(objOption);
```

These all snippets are taking almost same time. Is there any way to finish this up in 2-3 seconds?

Comment: **9000** items in a `selection box` ? I would recommend another solution which involves `textbox` and a free (or verified) text control to have what you (or the user) want selected. 9000 items to select is just horrible from UX point of view.

Comment: A select box (or drop-down list) with 9,000 items is practically unusable. Perhaps you could find a way to have a smaller set of items or use a different means of selection.

Comment: Do you know what takes most of the time? Creating the `<option>` elements or adding them to the `DOM`? How about creating a new `<select>` element, add the options to this element, and replace that element in the DOM? Anyway I really think that autocomplete will work much better here. No one can really use a select with 9K elements.

Comment: In theory: Adding to DOM will be the slowest. So you want to create all 9k in one go using either a string or a document fragment and only append to the DOM once everything is ready. In practice: most browsers will have alot of issues giving you a  decent framerate with 9k options. Really look into a different solution, since making a user search through 9k options is the best way to lose users.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses. I would try to load data as per need if there is no other solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you say you have tried to add the string and, to be honest, 9000 options are quite a lot. I would suggest using something like [chosen-select](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) in order to increase usability for such a huge select.

Anyway, I've tried to modify the select in a plain way and it works pretty fast.

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/950wws8r/1/).

What it does is to add the options as a string using the [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) jQuery method.

```
// number of options to insert
var noptions = 9000;

// number of current options
var nOpts = $('#huge_select option').length;

// current options html
var options = $('#huge_select').html();
for (var i = 0; i < noptions; ++i) {
    // add the html options to the current set
    options += "<option value='"+(i+nOpts)+"'>"+(i+nOpts)+"</option>";
}
// set the select html
$('#huge_select').html(options);
```

Comment: Yes thanks. html() is working superfast!! May be append is too slow. But now with html() it is working.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a custom select.

9000 items in the DOM is really slow, so your custom select has to have a virtualization feature (Only visible elements will be in the DOM)

Take a look here : [Virtual Select](https://github.com/SQiShER/virtual-select)

Comment: Thanks Steeve but I can't use any other plugin or library.

Comment: So you have to make your own ... because it's really not recommended to add 9000 elements in the DOM.