# speedup loadtime FORM with many 1020 SELECT options

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a FORM for every month where users can select two "from" and "to" times.

the  options are generated with PHP

```
<?php
for ($h = 7; $h <= 23; $h++) {
    for($m = 0; $m <= 59; $m++){
        echo $h.':'.$m.'<br/>';
    }
}
?>
```

So for January it loads 124 SELECT boxes with a total 1020 options.

this takes a whooping 2.8 seconds and annoys the users.

I can't think of a way to make this faster, 
Although I wonder if it is possible to show all the select boxes and if the are opened quickly load them with the times.

Any other idea is very much welcome.

Comment: Look this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41378248/adding-9000-options-dynamically-to-select-in-javascript-taking-too-long-on-ie/41378373#41378373

Comment: Just let them pop up when need dynamically with javascript.

Comment: Use JavaScript to render the select boxes on the client side.

Comment: @Mouser, that is a very nice idea. Just like setting a date in a calendar. -edit, after searching some more this seems to be called a time picker. But selecting 60 different times this way is a lot of clicks. I'll continue the search for an input box, with the extra popup option of a time picker. So the user can choose to type or click. Any suggestions are of course still very welcome.

Comment: It seems that using a jQuery, Javascript solution doesn't really help. I replaced the select options with en input field and used http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/ timepicker for the dropdown part. this gives me a speed increase of .2 seconds. When I remove the javascript and just use input boxes the load time becomes way faster 356 ms!. So I'm tempted to just use the input field and restrict it to time input only.